# Jquery Iterate over table and highlight cells that have changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is a history of a mysql record.

I want to add a button that will highlight the changes.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>600</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In this example the 600 would be highlighted as it was 300 and is now 600.

UPDATE: Thanks, I should have said there would be more than 2 rows. could be upto 20 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrf6d/2/) shows an example that will iterate over a table **of any size** and highlight the cells that have changed from the previous row.

```
$(function() {
var $rows = $("tr");

for (oldIndex = 0; oldIndex < $rows.length-1; oldIndex++) {
   var newIndex = oldIndex + 1;
    var $oldCols = $("td", $rows[oldIndex]);
    var $newCols = $("td", $rows[newIndex]);

    for (col = 0; col < $oldCols.length; col++) {
       var $newCol = $($newCols[col]);
        if ($($oldCols[col]).html() != $newCol.html()) {
            $newCol.addClass("highlight");
        }

    }


}
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should go along these lines. Assuming `set1` and `set2` are id's of two `tr`s here is a sample code (not tested).

```
var s1 = $('tr#set1 td');
var s2 = $('tr#set2 td');

var l = $('tr#set1 td').length;

for(var i =0; i<l i++){
   if(s1.eq(i).text() != s2.eq(i)){
      $(s2.eq(i)).highlight();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have said there would be more than 2 rows. could be upto 20 rows

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr.new td').each(function(i){
    //First TR td, Previous Rows

    td = $(this);
    check = $('table tr.prev td:eq('+i+')');

   if(td[0].innerText != check[0].innerText)
   {
        check.addClass('Changed');
   }
})​
```

This should do it but you need to add 2 classes:

```
<table>
<tr class="new">
  <td>150</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr class="prev">
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>600</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hjXZd/1/

Hope this helps.

---

I advise you to do an `attr` for each `TD` and place the mysql id in there so that you will only compare the rows that are the same in the DB, otherwise if your first list has more items then the second list the results will be corrupt.

Comment: Thanks, I should have said there would be more than 2 rows.  could be upto 20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has the id `results`, here is a solution:

```
var topRow = $('table#results tr:eq(0)');
var bottomRow = $('table#results tr:eq(1)');
topRow.find('td').each(function(index,item){
    var shadow = bottomRow.find('td:eq('+index+')');
    if($(item).contents().text()!=shadow.contents().text()){
        shadow.css({'background':'yellow'});
    }
});
```

Update: this solution compares the top row with all following ones:

```
$('table#results tr:eq(0) td').each(function(index,item){
    var orig = $(item).contents().text();
    $('table#results tr:gt(0)').find('td:eq('+index+')').each(function(index2,item2){
        var shadow = $(item2);
        if(orig!=shadow.contents().text()){
            shadow.css({'background':'yellow'});
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have said there would be more than 2 rows. could be upto 20 rows

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery .live you can handle multiple elements.
See here
http://api.jquery.com/live/

You have to give ids for the changed values.. which can be inside divs.
Hope td also may work

On button click using this .live you can chnage style of div

like highlighting.

Use addClass function os jquery itslef or you can add css  using jquery add